# Código PHP não está reconhecendo HTML

Tags: php

Eu escrevi um código HTML dentro de uma estrutura `for`, mas não está identificando, segue o código:

```
<form method="get" action="_modelophp.php">
    <h1>tabuada</h1>
    <select name="num">
        <?php
            for{$inicio=1;$inicio<=10;$inicio++}{
                echo "<option>$inicio</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Não sei se vai resolver mas tire isso do início do seu .PHP `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: O que acontece (defina _"não está identificando"_)? que erro aparece?

Comment: Seu `for` tem um erro, ele deveria ser assim, `for($inicio=1;$inicio<=10;$inicio++){`

Answer (score 1):

O seu `for` está mal estruturado.

Você está usando chavetas `{ }` inves de parênteses `( )`.

```
for{$inicio=1;$inicio<=10;$inicio++}{
    echo "<option>$inicio</option>";
}
```

Ou seja deverá estar assim o código

```
for($inicio=1;$inicio<=10;$inicio++){
    echo "<option>$inicio</option>";
}
```